# Storing gdal2tiles output directory in MongoDB, add as XYZ layer in OpenLayers

Tags: tiles, openlayers-2, mongodb, gdal2tiles

I am regularly running gdal2tiles.py which generates millions of XYZ image tiles for me. Right now I either store these tiles as flat files on a Windows Server file server or I upload a directory to Google cloud storage if needed.

I use a virtual directory or access the tiles directly from cloud storage to display XYZ tile layers in OpenLayers.

I would like to test storing the tile directories in MongoDB. Has anyone done a script to store the gdal2tiles.py output directly in MongoDB?

Or has anyone a script to upload an existing file directory into MongoDB?

Does anyone use MongoDB to store image tiles?

I would like to compare the performance with my traditional file server and Google cloud storage.